# Can I return Map collection in Scala using for-yield syntax?

Tags: scala, dictionary, yield, seq

I'm fairly new to Scala, so hopefully you tolerate this question in the case you find it noobish :)

I wrote a function that returns a Seq of elements using yield syntax:

```
def calculateSomeMetrics(names: Seq[String]): Seq[Long] = {
  for (name <- names) yield {
    // some auxiliary actions
    val metrics = somehowCalculateMetrics()
    metrics
  }
}
```

Now I need to modify it to return a Map to preserve the original names against each of the calculated values:

```
def calculateSomeMetrics(names: Seq[String]): Map[String, Long] = { ... }
```

I've attempted to use the same yield-syntax but to yield a tuple instead of a single element:

```
def calculateSomeMetrics(names: Seq[String]): Map[String, Long] = {
  for (name <- names) yield {
    // Everything is the same as before
    (name, metrics)
  }
}
```

However, the compiler interprets it `Seq[(String, Long)]`, as per the compiler error message

```
type mismatch;
  found   : Seq[(String, Long)]
  required: Map[String, Long]
```

So I'm wondering, what is the "canonical Scala way" to implement such a thing?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525115/how-to-choose-the-output-collection-type-in-seq-map

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either:

```
def calculateSomeMetrics(names: Seq[String]): Map[String, Long] = {
  (for (name <- names) yield {
    // Everything is the same as before
    (name, metrics)
  }).toMap
}
```

Or:

```
names.map { name =>
  // doStuff
  (name, metrics)
}.toMap
```

Comment: Thanks! Are those technically equivalent?

Comment: @VasiliyGalkin Yes, they are. The former gets compiled into the latter.

Comment: Great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 8):

The efficient way of creating different collection types is using [`scala.collection.breakOut`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html). It works with `Map`s and for comprehensions too:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

val x: Map[String, Int] = (for (i <- 1 to 10) yield i.toString -> i)(breakOut)
```

> x: Map[String,Int] = Map(8 -> 8, 4 -> 4, 9 -> 9, 5 -> 5, 10 -> 10, 6 -> 6, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 7 -> 7, 3 -> 3)

In your case it should work too:

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

def calculateSomeMetrics(names: Seq[String]): Map[String, Long] = {
  (for (name <- names) yield {
    // Everything is the same as before
    (name, metrics)
  })(breakOut)
}
```

Comparison with `toMap` solutions: before `toMap` creates an intermediate `Seq` of `Tuple2`s (which incidentally might be a `Map` too in certain cases) and from that it creates the `Map`, while `breakOut` omits this intermediate `Seq` creation and creates the `Map` directly instead of the intermediate `Seq`.

Usually this is not a huge difference in memory or CPU usage (+ GC pressure), but sometimes these things matter.

Comment: I would stray away from using `breakOut` until this specific code becomes a bottleneck. It is counter-intuitive to read and comprehend.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I agree, that is why I added the last sentence.

Comment: In my case the gain is not big enough compared to the possible "WTF's" that can be caused by the usage of `breakOut`. On another hand, today I've learned something new, so thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Note that [breakout is going away](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/05/30/tribulations-canbuildfrom.html#breakout-escape-hatch) in the new collections design.

Answer (score 1):

Several links here that either other people pointed me at or I managed to find out later on, just assembling them in a single answer for my future reference.

- `breakOut` - suggested by [Michał](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236045/micha%C5%82-politowski) in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553534/can-i-return-map-collection-in-scala-using-for-yield-syntax?noredirect=1#comment82065102_47553534)
- `toMap` - in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674639/scala-best-way-of-turning-a-collection-into-a-map-by-key)
- Great profound explanation on how `breakOut` works - in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1716558/5722863)

  - Note, though, that `breakOut` [is going away](http://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2017/05/30/tribulations-canbuildfrom.html#breakout-escape-hatch), as noted by [Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389146/karl-bielefeldt)

Comment: Thanks for the mention but Gábor's answer is older. I was just trying to quickly look for a duplicate and found the linked related question.