# map Range directly to Array

Tags: arrays, scala, vector, mapping, temporary

The following code creates a temporary Vector:

```
0.to(15).map(f).toArray
^^^^^^^^
Sequence
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    temp Vector
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  Array
```

The following code creates a temporary Array:

```
0.to(15).toArray.map(f)
^^^^^^^^
Sequence
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     temp Array
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  Array
```

Is there a way to map f over the Sequence and directly get an Array, without producing a temporary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `breakOut`:

```
val res: Array[Int] = 0.to(15).map(f)(scala.collection.breakOut)
```

or

```
0.to(15).map[Int, Array[Int]](f)(scala.collection.breakOut)
```

or use `view`:

```
0.to(15).view.map(f).to[Array]
```

See [this document](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html) for more details on views.

Comment: Can you briefly explain what `breakOut` does?

Comment: Also, it seems `0.to(15).map[Int, Array[Int]](f)` already works without the additional `(scala.collection.breakOut)` parameter list.

Comment: In short `breakOut` is a method that finds the correct `CanBuildFrom` instance based on the desired input and output type, which the compiler otherwise may not be able to correctly infer. With the right `CanBuildFrom` instance you can create a new type of collection while mapping over the original collection. More details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout

Comment: `0.to(15).map[Int, Array[Int]](_ + 1)` doesn't work for me in Scala 2.12.3 as the compiler complains about not being able to find `CanBuildFrom`.

Comment: In my case, `f` is a concrete function, so the compiler already knows the type. Does it work with `(_ + 1: Int => Int)` or something similar?

Comment: Nope - `0.to(15).map[Int, Array[Int]]((_ + 1): Int => Int)` doesn't compile with the same error as `0.to(15).map[Int, Array[Int]](_ + 1)` that basically says `CanBuildFrom` cannot be found.

Comment: You are correct. I just checked, and it fails to compile in 2.12.3 (but compiles successfully in 2.11.11)...

Answer (score 1):

```
(0 to 15).iterator.map(f).toArray
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the hand on how to build the initial `Range`, you could alternatively use [`Array.range(start, end)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html#range(start:Int,end:Int,step:Int):Array[Int]) from the `Array` [companion object](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/00f52f5b67412eb461e8646430b6d9e1fac5cd29/src/library/scala/Array.scala#L448) which creates a `Range` directly as an `Array` without cast:

```
Array.range(0, 15) // Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
```

which can be mapped from an `Array` to an `Array` as such:

```
Array.range(0, 15).map(f) // Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, ...)
```

*Note*: `Array.range(i, j)` is an equivalent of `i until j` (`i to j+1`) and not `i to j`.

---

Even shorter and in a single pass, but less readable, using [`Array.tabulate`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html#tabulate[T](n:Int)(f:Int=%3ET)(implicitevidence$14:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):Array[T]):

```
Array.tabulate(15)(f) // Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, ...)
```