# Scala: How to create a Map[K,V] from a Set[K] and a function from K to V?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

What is the best way to create a `Map[K,V]` from a `Set[K]` and function from `K` to `V`?

For example, suppose I have

```
scala> val s = Set(2, 3, 5)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 3, 5)
```

and

```
scala> def func(i: Int) = "" + i + i
func: (i: Int)java.lang.String
```

What is the easiest way of creating a `Map[Int, String](2 -> "22", 3 -> "33", 5 -> "55")`

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you are talking about a function or a method? You mention *twice* that you mean a function, but you use a method in your code example. Which is it?

Comment: The easiest way is as you did: Map[Int, String](2 -> "22", 3 -> "33", 5 -> "55")

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674639

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala best way of turning a Collection into a Map-by-key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674639/scala-best-way-of-turning-a-collection-into-a-map-by-key)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `foldLeft`:

```
val func2 = (r: Map[Int,String], i: Int) => r + (i -> func(i))
s.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int,String])(func2)
```

This will perform better than Jesper's solution, because `foldLeft` constructs the `Map` in one pass.  Jesper's code creates an intermediate data structure first, which then needs to be converted to the final `Map`.

**Update:** I wrote a [micro benchmark](https://gist.github.com/908732) testing the speed of each of the answers:

```
Jesper (original): 35s 738ms
Jesper (improved): 11s 618ms
           dbyrne: 11s 906ms
         Rex Kerr: 12s 206ms
          Eastsun: 11s 988ms
```

Looks like they are all pretty much the same as long as you avoid constructing an intermediate data structure.

Comment: What if I'd add a `.view` before the `.toMap` in my solution - would that prevent building the intermediate collection?

Comment: @Jesper: You would need to add the `.view` before the `map`, like this - `(s.view.map { i => i -> func(i) }).toMap`

Comment: @Jesper: Updated my answer. Shows what a dramatic improvement adding `.view` makes.

Answer (score 16):

What about this:

```
(s map { i => i -> func(i) }).toMap
```

This maps the elements of `s` to tuples `(i, func(i))` and then converts the resulting collection to a `Map`.

Note: `i -> func(i)` is the same as `(i, func(i))`.

dbyrne suggests creating a view of the set first (see his answer and comments), which prevents an intermediate collection from being made, improving performance:

```
(s.view map { i => i -> func(i) }).toMap
```

Comment: I wonder, is there a way to supply the func explicitly to toMap (i.e., specifying the implicit argument).

Comment: @subsub if you change `func` to: `def func(i: Int) = i -> ("" + i + i)` then you could do: `(s.view map func).toMap`. So, you'd let `func` return the tuple.

Answer (score 7):

```
scala> import collection.breakOut
import collection.breakOut

scala> val set = Set(2,3,5)
set: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(2, 3, 5)

scala> def func(i: Int) = ""+i+i
func: (i: Int)java.lang.String

scala> val map: Map[Int,String] = set.map(i => i -> func(i))(breakOut)
map: Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> 22, 3 -> 33, 5 -> 55)

scala>
```

Comment: What is the `breakOut` for exactly; what does it do?

Comment: @Jesper  It's a long story, I refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout for an introduction.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the existing answers,

```
Map() ++ set.view.map(i => i -> f(i))
```

is pretty short and performs as well as the faster answers (fold/breakOut).

(Note the view to prevent creation of a new collection; it does the remapping as it goes.)

Comment: @Luigi Plinge - Everything gets mapped to `()` if you use a function that returns `()`.

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions lack creativity. Here's my own version, though I'd really like to get rid of the `_.head` map.

```
s groupBy identity mapValues (_.head) mapValues func
```

Answer (score 1):

As with all great languages, there's a million ways to do everything.

Here's a strategy that zips the set with itself.

```
val s = Set(1,2,3,4,5)
Map(s.zip(s.map(_.toString)).toArray : _*)
```

EDIT: (_.toString) could be replaced with some function that returns something of type V

Comment: Clever, but slow.  The three fast solutions are 4x faster than this one.

Answer (score 1):

Without definition of func(i: Int) using "string repeating" operator *:

```
scala> s map { x => x -> x.toString*2 } toMap
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> 22, 3 -> 33, 5 -> 55)
```