# Avoid having to convert to an intermediate data-structure before calling .toMap in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's consider the following code:

```
Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .map(k => (k, if (k % 2 == 0) "even" else "odd"))
  .toMap
```

Is there a way to simplify this in Scala, avoiding the creation of the intermediate set? I'll be doing something performance-sensitive on big collections and it wouldn't hurt to get the `Map` created on-the-spot instead.

If nothing better comes along, I was thinking of ending up implementing something like this:

```
Map.from(S, k => if (k % 2 == 0) "even" else "odd"))
```

I'm still using Scala 2.12.

Thanks

Comment: Can use `scala.collection.breakOut`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `foldleft` :

```scala
(1 to 5).foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, String])(
  (r, k) => r + (k -> (if (k % 2 == 0) "even" else "odd"))
)
```

#### Edit

Or, to avoid intermediate collection in `toMap` approach, you can use `view` :

```scala
(1 to 5).view
  .map(k => (k, if (k % 2 == 0) "even" else "odd"))
  .toMap
```

[Scala: How to create a Map[K,V] from a Set[K] and a function from K to V?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582862/scala-how-to-create-a-mapk-v-from-a-setk-and-a-function-from-k-to-v)

Comment: I agree so much, I really prefer the toMap approach ! It's just an alternative, not sure if the best...

Comment: I've add the view option to my answer. It may answer your question on the 'intermediate set' issue.

Comment: Edited without type ascription

Comment: Since performance is a requirement in this case, and the `view` is not reused. It would be better to use `iterator` instead _(also that way the code is correct in 2.11 2.12 & 2.13)_.