# how to Create scala Map from list of optional items?

Tags: scala

Scala create the Map from an list of Option emelents?

```
myMap = (0 to r.numRows - 1).map { i =>
  if (Option(r.getValue(i,"Name")).isDefined)
    (r.getValue(i, "Name")) -> (r.getValue(i, "isAvailable").toString)
}.toMap
foo(myMap) //here At this point, I'm geting the exception
```

I have tried above code but not compiling:

```
Exception:
Error:(158, 23) Cannot prove that Any <:< (T, U).
                }.toMap
                  ^
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala best way of turning a Collection into a Map-by-key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674639/scala-best-way-of-turning-a-collection-into-a-map-by-key)

Comment: Why don't you use i while iterating by i ?

Comment: edited.
@suish No that's different

Comment: I guess r.getValue("Name") should be r.getValue(i, "Name")

Comment: What's the error message? You have a lot of strange syntax in this code. The if condition does not depend on`i` and you probably want an `else`condition

Comment: Yes.but that's not compilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this code:

```
val myMap = (0 until r.numRows) flatMap { i =>
  for {
    name <- Option(r.getValue(i, "Name"))
    available = r.getValue(i, "isAvailable").toString
  } yield (name, available)
}.toMap
foo(myMap)
```

Your problem is most likely that you use `if` without `else`, and `if` is an expression in scala, which means it evaluates to something.

```
if (2 > 3) true
```

is equivalent to

```
if (2 > 3) true else ()
```

so the type is the common supertype of `Unit` and `Boolean` which is `Any` and this is the error you get.

Note that you can replace `to` and `-1` with `until` which does the same thing but is more readable.

You shouldn't really check `Option` with `isDefined` and perform action on result if that's true, to do this you use `map` operation.

To explain my implementation a little: the `for` part will evaluate to `Option[(String, String)]`, and will contain your tuple if `"Name"` key was present, otherways `None`. Conceptually, `flatMap` will first change your range of indices to a sequence of `Option[(String, String)]`, and then flatten it, i.e. remove all `None`s and unwrap all `Some`s.

If you want to check `"isAvailable"` for null as well, you can do similar thing

```
for {
  name      <- Option(r.getValue(i, "Name"))
  available <- Option(r.getValue(i, "isAvailable"))
} yield (name, available.toString)
```