# How to create a map with indexed keys in scala?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to create a Map with idiomatic Scala with a sequenced key and a value of zero.
I was thinking something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674639/scala-best-way-of-turning-a-collection-into-a-map-by-key):

```
(0 to 445) map (_ => _ -> 0).toMap
```

but that fails the IDE (IDEA) complains with `cannot resolve symbol ->`

and the compiler complains about `missing parameter type`

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the placeholder `_` once in a function declaration for each argument. What you want is this:

```
(0 to 445) map (_ -> 0).toMap
```

or an explicit value like this

```
(0 to 445) map (x => x -> 0).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have is to use `zipAll`:

```
0.to(445).zipAll(Seq.empty[Int], 0, 0).toMap
```

or `zip`:

```
0.to(445).zip(Seq.fill(445)(0)).toMap
```

or:

```
Map.from(0.to(445).map(_ -> 0))
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/EhSq90rFQ1S7v11QjYfqjA/1).